# how can i make insert method in binary search tree without recursion

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

i wonder how to make insertion method without recursion.
I made it, but there's something wrong.  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'item' occured.

I know what this error means, but I can't understand why this happend. parent is not None... it moves to curr so it can have item... why this happens?
this is my code.

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
class BSTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        parent = None
        curr = self.root

        while curr is not None:
            if data < curr.item:
                parent = curr
                curr = curr.left

            elif data > curr.item:
                parent = curr
                curr = curr.right

            else:
                return False

        if curr is None:
            if parent is None:
                newNode = BSTNode(data)
                self.root = newNode

            if data < parent.item:
                newNode = BSTNode(data)
                curr = newNode
                return True

            elif data > parent.item:
                newNode = BSTNode(data)
                curr = newNode
                return True
            
    def search(self, data):
        curr = self.root
        while curr is not None:
            if data < curr.item:
                curr = curr.left
            elif data > curr.item:
                curr = curr.right
            else:
                return True
        return False


    def delete(self, data):
        parent = None
        curr = self.root
        while curr is not None:
            if data < curr.item:
                parent = curr
                curr = curr.left
            elif data > curr.item:
                parent = curr
                curr = curr.right
            else:
                break

        if curr is None:
            return False

        if curr.left is None:

            if parent is None:
                self.root = curr.right

            else:
                if data < parent.item:
                    parent.left = curr.right
                else:
                    parent.right = curr.right
        elif curr.right is None:
            if parent is None:
                self.root = curr.left
            else:
                if data < parent.item:
                    parent.left = curr.left
                else:
                    parent.right = curr.left
        else:

            parentMaxNode = curr
            maxNode = curr.left
            while maxNode.right is not None:
                parentMaxNode = maxNode
                maxNode = maxNode.right
            curr.item = maxNode.item
            if parentMaxNode.right is maxNode:
                parentMaxNode.right = maxNode.left
            else:
                parentMaxNode.left = maxNode.left
        return True
```

Comment: Could you show the entire code where you create instances of the classes/ apply methods instead of just the class definitions themselves

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the problem with insert method and i think my code below is work for you

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
class BSTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def insert(self, item):
        # if the tree is empty, the new item becomes the root node
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = BSTNode(item)
        else:
            # find the parent node of the new item
            parent = self.root
            while True:
                if item < parent.item:
                    # if the item is less than the parent node,
                    # insert the item to the left of the parent node
                    if parent.left is None:
                        parent.left = BSTNode(item)
                        break
                    else:
                        parent = parent.left
                else:
                    # if the item is greater than or equal to the parent node,
                    # insert the item to the right of the parent node
                    if parent.right is None:
                        parent.right = BSTNode(item)
                        break
                    else:
                        parent = parent.right
```

Comment: could you plz explain why my insert method doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part at the end of the `insert` function:

```
        if data < parent.item:
            newNode = BSTNode(data)
            curr = newNode
            return True

        elif data > parent.item:
            newNode = BSTNode(data)
            curr = newNode
            return True
```

The statement `curr = newNode` just assigns a node reference to a *variable*. Assigning to a variable can **never** mutate an object (like a node or a list). If you need to mutate a list (like attaching a left or right child to a node), you really need to assign to an *attribute* of an existing node (the parent).

So that part of the code must be replaced with this:

```
            if data < parent.item:
                newNode = BSTNode(data)
                parent.left = newNode
                return True

            elif data > parent.item:
                newNode = BSTNode(data)
                parent.right = newNode
                return True
```

...which can be shortened to:

```
            newNode = BSTNode(data)
            if data < parent.item:
                parent.left = newNode
            elif data > parent.item:
                parent.right = newNode
            return True
```

(Note that at that point it is already guaranteed that `data != parent.item`)